# Escape unicode characters in Go JSON so the output matches Python

Tags: json, go, unicode

In Python 2.7, if I encode JSON I get unicode-escaped strings:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = {"text": "三杯雞"}
>>> print(json.dumps(s))
```

it gives this output:

```
{"text": "\u4e09\u676f\u96de"}
```

But in Go, similar code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Food struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    food := Food{Name: "三杯雞"}
    v, _ := json.Marshal(food)
    fmt.Println(string(v))
}
```

Gives this:

```
{"name":"三杯雞"}
```

The Chinese characters are not escaped. I am porting API endpoints from Python to Go - how can I get it to have the same escaped output as Python?

I tried variations using `strconv.QuoteToASCII`, but they result in the unicode being double-escaped:

```
func main() {
    s := strconv.QuoteToASCII("三杯雞")
    s = strings.Trim(s, "\"")
    food := Food{Name: s}
    v, _ := json.Marshal(food)
    fmt.Println(string(v))
}
```

Outputs:

```
{"name":"\\u4e09\\u676f\\u96de"}
```

Comment: Does it truly matter? Both JSON files are valid and equivalent to each other. See http://ideone.com/e8Zipj

Comment: @Robᵩ good question, and probably not... Though I think your example only proves that the Python `json.loads` function loads it into an equivalent object representation. Printing out the raw JSON string certainly will give you different-looking things. I don't want API clients to notice that we switched representation format, and I wouldn't want any API clients in the wild to break because of our internal change. Who knows what they're doing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to use the `strconv.QuoteToASCII` method inside of a custom JSON marshaler:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type Food struct {
    Name utf8String `json:"name"`
}

type utf8String string

func (s utf8String) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(strconv.QuoteToASCII(string(s))), nil
}

func main() {
    food := Food{Name: utf8String("三杯雞")}
    v, _ := json.Marshal(food)
    fmt.Println(string(v))
}
```

Output:

```
{"name":"\u4e09\u676f\u96de"}
```

This has the drawback that you can't use a plain `string` type in the struct definition, but the final output is ASCII-quoted, just like in Python.

Comment: How about applying `QuoteToASCII()` after the marshaling?

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok Applying `QuoteToASCII()` after marshaling will result in JSON-quotes also getting escaped, e.g. `"{\"name\":\"\u4e09\u676f\u96de\"}"`

Comment: `QuoteToASCII` won't work because it doesn't encode characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane correctly, e.g. in JSON the string `""` should be encoded as `"\ud83d\ude0a"` and not `"\U0001f60a"`. I have a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77390995/14430952