# Escape unicode characters in json encode golang

Tags: go, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

Given the following example:

```
func main() {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    enc := json.NewEncoder(buf)
    toEncode := []string{"hello", "wörld"}
    enc.Encode(toEncode)
    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```

I would like to have the output presented with escaped Unicode characters:

> ["hello","w\u00f6rld"]

Rather than:

> ["hello","wörld"]

I have attempted to write a function to quote the Unicode characters using `strconv.QuoteToASCII` and feed the results to `Encode()` however that results in double escaping:

```
func quotedUnicode(data []string) []string {
    for index, element := range data {                                                
                quotedUnicode := strconv.QuoteToASCII(element) 
                // get rid of additional quotes                         
                quotedUnicode = strings.TrimSuffix(quotedUnicode, "\"") 
                quotedUnicode = strings.TrimPrefix(quotedUnicode, "\"") 
                data[index] = quotedUnicode                               
         }                                                                                                                                    
         return data                                                             
}
```

> ["hello","w\\u00f6rld"]

How can I ensure that the output from json.Encode contains correctly escaped Unicode characters?

Comment: The `encoding/json` package generates valid JSON, it shouldn't matter if a specific character is escaped or not. Why must it be escaped?

Comment: You could do something like: https://play.golang.org/p/QG9_92D2nqt - however, it will ruin the ergonomics of your code.

Comment: @icza a valid question. The simple answer is I need to match the output from a previous version of the API in order to not break compatibility (and yes, the consumers of the API is handling JSON incorrectly, but none the less...)

Comment: Then you have to implement your own MarshalJSON method on appropriate (new) types.

Comment: I don't think comparing JSON outputs as string is wise, the same JSON data can be represented in numerous forms. So instead you should rewrite your "JSON comparator" to compare the actual data the JSON represents, and not the raw JSON text. Then escaping wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The `encoding/json` package does not support this, but you can implement it yourself.

For each string field of your struct change its type from `string` to `json.RawMessage` and quote it using the following function:

```golang
func QuoteToJSON(s string) json.RawMessage {
    var sb strings.Builder
    for _, r := range s {
        if r > 0xFFFF {
            r1, r2 := utf16.EncodeRune(r)
            sb.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\\u%04X", r1))
            sb.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\\u%04X", r2))
        } else if r > 0x7F {
            sb.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\\u%04X", r))
        } else {
            sb.WriteRune(r)
        }
    }
    return json.RawMessage(`"` + sb.String() + `"`)
}
```

Complete example:

```golang
type Greeting struct {
    Text string
}

func (g *Greeting) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        Text json.RawMessage `json:"text"`
    }{
        Text: QuoteToJSON(g.Text),
    })
}

func main() {
    out := Greeting{"Hí, !"}
    dat, _ := json.Marshal(&out)
    fmt.Println(string(dat)) // {"text":"H\u00ED, \uD83D\uDE0A!"}

    var in Greeting
    json.Unmarshal(dat, &in)
    fmt.Println(in.Text) // "Hí, !"
}
```

Go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/Jk6GZwdvyvm

Some folks suggest using `strconv.QuoteToASCII` but this has two problems:

1. Strings will be double escaped when they are marshaled, e.g. they'll look like `"\\u4e09"` instead of `"\u4e09"`.
2. JSON requires characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane to be encoded with UTF-16 surrogates, e.g. the string `""` should be encoded as `"\ud83d\ude0a"` and not `"\U0001f60a"`.